# Unit testing mongodb connection with mocha

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocha.js

I am new to NodeJS+mocha testing. I am going to test a database connection.

test.js

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var db=require("../model/mongoDBhandler");

describe('Database', function(){
       it('connecting the database', function(done){
        db.connect();
        done();
    })
})
```

../mode/mongoDBHandler.js

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

exports.connect=function(done){
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb';
    // Use connect method to connect to the Server
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        console.log("Connected correctly to server");
        db.close();
    });
    done();
    console.log("finished");
}
```

But when I run mocha it does not print "Connected correctly to server" or "finished". I tried various codes about asynchronous methods. But they did not work. I may be doing a basic mistake. Could you please help me to figure that out?